# show the condition $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n} <1$ implies that $s_n \rightarrow 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{s_n\}$ be a sequence of positive numbers. Show that the condition
$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n} < 1$
implies that $s_n \rightarrow 0$.

I cannot think of how to start. Can someone help? Thank you.

Comment: For $n$ sufficiently large, $s_{n+1}<rs_n$ for some $r<1$. Show that for all $k>0$, $s_{n+k}< r^k s_n$. Now take the limit as $k\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*:

(First assume that the sequence converges.)

Assume for contradiction that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} s_n =a$ where $a>0$.

What can you say about  $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} s_{n+1} $?

What can you then say about  $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n} $?

(Then see what happens if the sequence diverges. Is it possible?)

Answer (score 2):

- Since $\lim \frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}=L <1$ it follows that for $n$ great enough $s_{n+1}/s_n <(L+1)/2<1$. This gives you the monotonicity of $(s_n)$ for $n$ great enough.
- $(s_n)$ is decreasing and bounded by $0$, therefore...
- If $s_n \to a>0$ then the limit tells you $1<1$, therefore...

Answer (score 1):

Consider the series: s(1) + s(2) + s(3) +...+ s(n) +..... The condition that lim s(n+1)/s(n) < 1 implies that this series converges by ratio test. This means the n-th term s(n) must have
limit = 0.

Comment: This is a very roundabout argument...

Answer (score 1):

Even more: if for some constant $0<c<1$:
$$\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}\le c$$
for $n$ large enough then
$$0\le s_n\le Mc^n$$
and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=0.$$