# Analysis Lemma Proof

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $$x_n>0, \forall n \in N$$ is such that $$lim \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=a<1$$ then $$lim x_n=0 $$ I feel absolutely frustrated, because I tried a lot on this issue and couldn't develop anything. Does anyone have anything that can help me?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2508842/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/714558/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1242096/42969

Comment: $~0 < a < 1 \implies \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a^n = 0.$

Comment: I managed to solve it!